# How to pull specific content from xml (on page load)?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am working on **html/js** code as shown below belonging to the following [url](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/) in which all the content **in black** are pull from the [xml](http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml)

```
<div class="container-wrap background--gray-light-2 cf">
    <div class="section container container--mid container--margbot background--white entry-content cf">
        <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/FZ8yNTef.js"></script>
        <center>
            <div id="podcast" align="center"></div>
        </center>
        <script>
            var PodcastplayerInstance = jwplayer("podcast");
            PodcastplayerInstance.setup({
                playlist: "//www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml",
                androidhls: true,
                preload: "auto",
                height: 200,
                width: 400,
                visualplaylist: false,
                stretching: "fill",
                "plugins": {
                    "http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/listy.js": {},
                    'viral-2': {'oncomplete': 'False', 'onpause': 'False', 'functions': 'All'}
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div><!-- .container-wrap -->
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what php/javascript code I need to add above so that it fetches only **April 3, 2019** or **April 1, 2019** or **only one content** (as shown below) **ON PAGE LOAD** from the vertical rectangle box from here http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/

[image]

At this moment, **5 contents (in a black rectangle box)** are being pulled from xml.

Used the following logic in order to pull specific content from xml:

```
 $context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
 $url = 'http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml';

 $xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
 $itemarray = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item[1]");
```

I am wondering how I can integrate it with the above html/js code. The value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) of item array can be shuffle depending on requirement.

Comment: Can you control what is returned in the XML here http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml

Comment: No, I cannot control what is returned in the xml there.

Comment: ok so you just want to read parts of the XML using Javascript. Have you tried this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: No, I didn't try that. I am going to have a look.

Comment: The content in the rectangular black box is definitely coming from here http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml

Comment: I have been playing with it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgyLYZ?editors=1001

Comment: But you are hard coding the content. The content gonna change every week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript Solution

You can use the JW PLayer [playlist API](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#playlist), where you'd use [`jwplayer().getPlaylistItem()`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#jwplayergetplaylistitemindex) to retrieve just a specific item in the playlist. And in your case, the `jwplayer()` is `PodcastplayerInstance`, and note that the index is 0-based. So you can add this *after* you call `PodcastplayerInstance.setup()`:

```
var item = PodcastplayerInstance.getPlaylistItem(0);
console.log( item.title, item.description, item ); // for debugging/testing purposes
```

And you can use jQuery (which is - as of writing - being used on the [page](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/)) to update the "vertical rectangle box" which (based on the current markup), is inside `div#podcast_listy_pl_panel`:

```
var $item = jQuery( '#podcast_listy_pl_panel .listy-item' );
$item.find( '.listy-title' ).html( item.title + ' <span class="listy-duration"></span>' );
$item.find( '.listy-description' ).html( item.description );
```

To get the second, third, etc. item, just change the index:

```
var item = PodcastplayerInstance.getPlaylistItem(1); // get the second item; index = 1
```

### PHP Solution

You already have the code which fetches the content of the remote [XML file](http://www.cpac.ca/tip-podcast/jwplayer.xml), so you could just add this right below where the `$itemarray` is defined (i.e. *after* the following line: `$itemarray = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item[1]");`):

```php
$item = $itemarray ? (array) $itemarray[0] : null;
if ( $item ) :
?>
<div class="listy-textwrapper">
    <span class="listy-title">
        <?php echo $item['title']; ?>
        <span class="listy-duration"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="listy-description">
        <?php echo $item['description']; ?>
    </span>
</div>
<?php
endif; // end $item
```

And to get the second item, just use `item[2]` like so:

```
$itemarray = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item[2]"); // get the second item; index = 2, not 1
```

But the `$item` here always points to `$itemarray[0]`:

```
$item = $itemarray ? (array) $itemarray[0] : null;
```

Comment: Thanks Sally. I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620596/add-class-in-javascript-jquery-when-a-particular-timezone-is-selected-from-ui). Its not similar, I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: You're welcome. And regarding that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620596/add-class-in-javascript-jquery-when-a-particular-timezone-is-selected-from-ui), I wanted to help, but looking at the [page](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/), I guess the issue is solved?

Comment: No, its not working. If you check the website, in it shows showing under timezone ET is 100% correct as they are falling under correct dates but for other timezones (PT, MT, CT, AT, NT) some shows are not under correct date.

Comment: Yes, but I'll get back to you later.