# add class in javascript/jquery when a particular timezone is selected from UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, timezone

I am working on a html code as shown below which is from this [url](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/). In it **shows showing under timezone ET is 100% correct as they are falling under correct dates** but for other timezones (PT, MT, CT, AT, NT) some shows are not under correct date.

The screen-shot beneath the code belong to the class ***schedule-action-bar*** from the code below. (removed ct, at, and nt from the code at this moment in order to minimize my question)

```
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule-wrapper" data-timezone="et">  <!-- Line#A  -->
   <div class="schedule-action-bar">   <!-- this is on UI, from there we can select PT, MT and ET timezones -->
      <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
         Select your timezone:            
         <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-pt" data-timezone="pt">PT</button>
            </li>
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-mt" data-timezone="mt">MT</button>
            </li>
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-ct" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="schedule-show">
      Show#A
      <div class="schedule-show-time">
         <time datetime="22:00 10-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">22:00</time>
         <time datetime="23:00 10-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">23:00</time>
         <time datetime="01:00 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">01:00</time>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->
   <div class="schedule-show">
      Show#B
      <div class="schedule-show-time">
         <time datetime="23:30 10-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">23:30</time>
         <time datetime="00:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">00:30</time>
         <time datetime="02:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">02:30</time>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->
   <div class="schedule-show">
      Show#C
      <div class="schedule-show-time">
         <time datetime="00:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">00:30</time>
         <time datetime="01:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">01:30</time>
         <time datetime="03:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">03:30</time>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->
</div>
```

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

At line#A when **data-timezone="pt" or data-timezone="mt"** (anyone of them from the UI) is selected then it should display like this with datebar at the top:

**For timezone `pt`**,  it should look like this with date at the top

```
   April 10
   22:00    Show#A
   23:30    Show#B

   April 11
   00:30   Show#C
```

**For timezone `mt`**,  it should look like this with date at the top

```
   April 10
   23:00    Show#A


   April 11
   00:30    Show#B
   01:30    Show#C
```

*At this moment, it does show date. Just some shows in timezones apart from et are not under correct dates. Haven't included timezone `et` as it working fine.*

This is what I have tried (I have placed my script in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5bmoe4tq/ as I want to make the question short) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I do not see any javascript in your post.  Have you attempted any?

Comment: yes. I am adding now.

Comment: @Steve0 I have Added in the question.

Comment: The above code belongs to this [website](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/) but the dates are not showing properly for different timezones.

Comment: you do not update the wrappers timezone.  It really feels like the button click should action the rest of the code too, not a wrapper click.  Also there is no `.schedule-date-bar` so I am not entirely sure what you are shooting for there.

Comment: There is no schedule-date-bar in the html. I removed it from my codebase as you can see in the website, its not rendering the shows properly under  correct date.

Comment: @charlietfl I think you didn't get my question ? If you check the [website](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/) and in there if we select different timezones then some shows are not under correct date.

Comment: Well question expected results shows changing the structure to date with shows as children and html shown is opposite

Comment: Also don't need all those repetitive if/else that all do basically the same thing

Comment: @charlietfl Correct I have to clean the code but I am not sure if we can achieve through javascript/jquery.

Comment: @charlietfl At time moment, I have removed the code inside schedule-date-bar class and trying to add a date through javascript/jquery

Comment: Your logic is flawed in your `if($(time).attr('data-timezone') === 'nt')`. That only checks the very first one in page. Same with getting a datetime attribute

Comment: I would start over completely and focus on iterating instances with one process for all timezones/ all shows

Comment: Start with `$('.schedule-show').each ...`

Comment: @charlietfl I would definitelty start with this but I am confused with the logic a bit    `jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.schedule-show').each(function () {
        });
    }   )`

Comment: Then you look inside each instance at each time within that instance as well as get the time to display for that instance

Comment: @charlietfl I am wondering, if you can give me more pointer or snippets of code.

Comment: Within that `each` .. `$(this)` is the container element. Then the time elements are `$(this).find('time')`

Comment: Ok, after that ?

Comment: Then do instance specific logic and manipulation...working within only that show. Every iteration of the loop is a different show

Comment: @flash, I think the problem can be solved by editing the (PHP?) code which outputs these elements: `.schedule-date-bar` and `.schedule-show`. Because from what I could tell, the times are supposed to be under their own date (bar) - but for certain `.schedule-show`, they are incorrectly placed. And if it's not possible to correctly position the elements (without using JavaScript), then you should probably use `data-date` as in `<div class="schedule-date-bar" data-date="17-04-2019">` - this is identical to the approach in the current answer. Can you change the elements (i.e. their markup)?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to handle one of the button clicks instead of a wrapper click.

I am not entirely clear what `DOM` manipulation you are shooting for so I implemented a container(s) to hold the show times, and populate them

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //this function will update the timezone when you click a button
  $("button[data-timezone]").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".schedule-wrapper").attr("data-timezone", $(this).attr("data-timezone"));
    //clear the day-schedules
    $(".day-schedule").empty();
    //repopulate based on the selected timezone
    populateDays();
  });
  populateDays();
});

function populateDays() {
  let targetZone = $('#js-schedule-wrapper').attr('data-timezone');
  $.each($(".day-schedule"), function(idx, elem) {
    let day = $(elem).attr("day");
    $(elem).text(day);
    //get the times for the day, show be damned
    let showtimes = $(`time[data-timezone=${targetZone}][datetime~='${day}']`);
    $.each(showtimes, function(i, time){
      $(elem).append($(time).clone());  //copy the time into the days schedule
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.day-schedule {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.schedule-show {
  display: none
}
time{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule-wrapper" data-timezone="pt"> // Line#A
  <div class="schedule-action-bar">
    <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
      Select your timezone:
      <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
        <li>
          <button id="js-time-pt" data-timezone="pt">PT</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button id="js-time-mt" data-timezone="mt">MT</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button id="js-time-ct" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div day='10-04-2019' class='day-schedule'>
  </div>
  <div day='11-04-2019' class='day-schedule'>
  </div>
  <div class="schedule-show">
    Show#A
    <div class="schedule-show-time">
      <time datetime="22:00 10-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">22:00</time>
      <time datetime="23:00 10-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">23:00</time>
      <time datetime="01:00 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">01:00</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .schedule-show -->
  <div class="schedule-show">
    Show#B
    <div class="schedule-show-time">
      <time datetime="23:30 10-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">23:30</time>
      <time datetime="00:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">00:30</time>
      <time datetime="02:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">02:30</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .schedule-show -->
  <div class="schedule-show">
    Show#C
    <div class="schedule-show-time">
      <time datetime="00:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">00:30</time>
      <time datetime="01:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">01:30</time>
      <time datetime="03:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">03:30</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .schedule-show -->
</div>
```

After reviewing your linked page, it looks like you can accomplish what you want in the following way.  Note that I had to add the day to the `schedule-date-bar` so that the javascript could find it easier.

1. Interate the shows (they must be on the page in order)
2. Find the target "date-bar" for the show
3. Move that show to the date-bar it should be under.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //this function will update the timezone when you click a button
  $("button[data-timezone]").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".schedule-wrapper").attr("data-timezone", $(this).attr("data-timezone"));
    //manipulate in case the day changed based on the selected timezone
    populateDays();
  });
  populateDays();
});

function populateDays() {
  let targetZone = $('#js-schedule-wrapper').attr('data-timezone');
  let showtimes = $(`time[data-timezone=${targetZone}]`);
  $.each(showtimes.get().reverse(), function(i, time) {
    let targetDate = $(time).attr("datetime").split(" ")[1];
    let insertionPoint = $(`.schedule-date-bar[day='${targetDate}']`);
    $(time).closest(".schedule-show").insertAfter(insertionPoint);
  });
}
```

```css
.day-schedule {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

time {
  display: none;
}

[data-timezone=pt] [data-timezone=pt],
[data-timezone=mt] [data-timezone=mt],
[data-timezone=et] [data-timezone=et] {
  display: block;
}

.schedule-date-bar {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #34383b;
  background-color: rgba(169, 178, 177, .15);
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.1;
}

.schedule-show {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d8d8;
  max-width: 697px;
  max-width: 69.7rem;
  margin-left: auto;
}

time {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 16.66%;
  flex: 1 0 16.66%;
  max-height: 36px;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #34383b;
  line-height: 2.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule-wrapper" data-timezone="pt"> // Line#A
  <div class="schedule-action-bar">
    <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
      Select your timezone:
      <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
        <li>
          <button id="js-time-pt" data-timezone="pt">PT</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button id="js-time-mt" data-timezone="mt">MT</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button id="js-time-ct" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div day='10-04-2019' class="schedule-date-bar">
    April 10 </div>
  <div day='11-04-2019' class="schedule-date-bar">
    April 11 </div>
  <div class="schedule-show">
    Show#A
    <div class="schedule-show-time">
      <time datetime="22:00 10-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">22:00</time>
      <time datetime="23:00 10-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">23:00</time>
      <time datetime="01:00 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">01:00</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .schedule-show -->
  <div class="schedule-show">
    Show#B
    <div class="schedule-show-time">
      <time datetime="23:30 10-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">23:30</time>
      <time datetime="00:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">00:30</time>
      <time datetime="02:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">02:30</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .schedule-show -->
  <div class="schedule-show">
    Show#C
    <div class="schedule-show-time">
      <time datetime="00:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="pt">00:30</time>
      <time datetime="01:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="mt">01:30</time>
      <time datetime="03:30 11-04-2019" data-timezone="et">03:30</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .schedule-show -->
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get my question ? If you check the [website](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/) and in there if we select different timezones then some shows are not under correct date.

Comment: It is just changing time but dates are fixed at their place.

Comment: At time moment, I have removed the code inside schedule-date-bar class from my codebase and trying to add a date through javascript/jquery

Comment: I just use it for reference, to get the times from.  In this snippet I just use it for information storage.

Comment: why did you add this   `<div day='10-04-2019' class='day-schedule'>
  </div>
  <div day='11-04-2019' class='day-schedule'>
  </div>` ? Its not inside my dom.

Comment: I wanted somewhere to insert the schedule times.  I think this loosely corresponds to your `schedule-date-bar`.  Point is you need to be able to rearrange things in your `DOM`

Comment: Your answer is working perfectly with your code but in my case I can't alter the DOM which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: You have added this   `<div day='10-04-2019' class='day-schedule'>
  </div>
  <div day='11-04-2019' class='day-schedule'>` in your html code and you r trying to add script based on that. But in my case, I can't do that. You have the website to get more idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191626/discussion-between-steve0-and-flash).

Comment: Did my modifications and new snippet get you what you needed?

Comment: No, it didn't work. Its my fault also as I am not explaining the question properly.

Comment: Do you have any other way to approach this question ? This is the [website](http://www.cpac.ca/en/full-schedule/). 
Shows showing under timezone ET is 100% correct as they are falling under correct dates but for other timezones (PT, MT, CT, AT, NT) some shows are not under correct date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) and that's why this library exists

You can easily update a time to another time zone by the next instruction:

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```